# Upgrade an existing stellar core

Tags: stellar-core, upgrade

How do I upgrade an existing stellar-core to the latest updated code in git?

I tried finding out but couldn't get any details.

**NOTE: I have built stellar_core from source code and not used the docker.**

Answer (score 1):

There is no trick,
just pull the source code again (latest version) and build it again

Comment: Will this upgrade the changes related to base reserve as well? The minimum base reserve is 0.5 XLM now. I want that as a major update.

Comment: Also, will this not erase the xdr files in buckets folder? If I delete existing core and get the latest version, will this create a problem as I have data in DB ? Will the core b in sync post making the changes?

Comment: building new version is not destructive, it won't hurt your buckets/DB. I guess you're on your own network if asking about base reserve? After update your nodes need to vote for upgrade https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html#network-configuration
Since it's your own network you can choose base reserve value yourself. The only problem is that SDK may not play nice with it